# Use ngx-joyride as a wrapper for a component(card) that is render with *ngFor

Tags: angular6

I am rendering cards as grid , I have list of objects and I am using *ngFor to iterate and display cards(card Component per object). I wan to wrap each card with ngx-joyride so when new user get in for first time can see the tour text per card. 
[I have this right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE4Jl.png)

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let file of files ">

    <app-card  [data]="file"> </app-card>

  </ng-container>
```

I want to have something like this :

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let file of files ">
    <div joyrideStep="firstStep" title="Page Title" text="Main title!"> 
      <app-card  [data]="file"> </app-card>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

But when i tried that , its effecting the whole style and its not applied on every cards i have within the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question but I can't comment for clarification (due to reputation) so I thought that I would try and offer an answer based on my own experience with Joyride and an `*ngFor`. Apologies if I am way off of what you need.

For what I think you need my recommendation would be to put the joyride attributes on the `<app-card>` component like so:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let file of files ">
    <app-card [data]="file" joyrideStep="firstStep" title="Page Title" text="Main title!"> </app-card>
</ng-container>
```

If you want the tutorial to highlight a specific element of the card (like a button on the card) then you will need the joyride attributes to be on that specific element within the `<app-card>` component. In my experience so far however this will make the tutorial appear only for the last instance of the `*ngFor`

Hope that helps :-)

**EDIT:**

Actually when I tested the above I found a slightly more effective way.

If I do what I said above then joyride does not seem to highlight the card component - so it looks like a general tutorial step that is not focused on anything.

If, instead, I set the joyride attributes on the **highest parent element** within your `card.component.html` file then my card element was highlighted correctly.

Like so:

`card.component.html`

```
<div class="container-fluid" joyrideStep="step" title="Test" text="test">
  <div class="card">
    Card Content Here...
  </div>
</div>
```

Again - I hope that helps.